# how to update and delete withdout reloading the page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm trying to update and delete some notes that are on cloud firestore via redux, every thing seems to work fine but i should reload the page to see the results

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import authReducer from './authReducer';
import noteReducer from './noteReducer';
import { firestoreReducer } from 'redux-firestore';
import { firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    note: noteReducer,
    firestore: firestoreReducer,
    firebase: firebaseReducer
});

export default rootReducer;



const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
        reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
        reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, {useFirestoreForProfile: true, userProfile: 'users', attachAuthIsReady: true})
    )

);
```

this is my note action:

```
export const createNote = (note) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        const profile = getState().firebase.profile;
        const authorId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
        firestore.collection('notes').add({
            ...note,
            authorFirstName: profile.firstName,
            authorLastName: profile.lastName,
            authorId: authorId,
            createdAt: new Date(),
        })
        .then(() => {
            dispatch({type: 'CREATE_NOTE_SUCCESS', note});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            dispatch({type: 'CREATE_NOTE_ERROR', err});
        })

    };
};

export const updateNote = (updatedNote, id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firestore.collection('notes').doc(id.toString()).update({
        ...updatedNote,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        })
            .then(() => {
                dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_NOTE_SUCCESS'}, updatedNote)
            })
            .catch(() => {
                dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_NOTE_ERROR'})
            })
    };
};

export const deleteNote = (id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firestore.collection('notes').doc(id.toString()).delete()
        .then(() => {
            dispatch({type: 'DELETE_NOTE_SUCCESS'}, id);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            dispatch({type: 'DELETE_NOTE_ERROR'})
        });
    };
};
```

this is my notereducer

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';
import { updateObject } from '../../../shared/utility';

const initState = {
    notes: [],
    id: null,
    error: null,
    changed: false
};

const noteReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.CREATE_NOTE_SUCCESS:
            return updateObject(state, {error: null , changed: true})

        case actionTypes.CREATE_NOTE_ERROR:
            return updateObject(state, {error: action.err});

        case actionTypes.UPDATE_NOTE_SUCCESS:
            return updateObject(state, {error: null, changed: true});

        case actionTypes.UPDATE_NOTE_ERROR:
            return updateObject(state, {error: action.err});

        case actionTypes.DELETE_NOTE_SUCCESS:
            return updateObject(state, {   
            notes: state.notes.filter(note => note.id !== action.id),
            error: null,
            changed: true
            });

        case actionTypes.DELETE_NOTE_ERROR:
            return updateObject(state, {error: action.err});

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default noteReducer;
```

here are some parts of my code, i don't know what part I've done wrong or what I've missed, i really appreciate your help

Comment: How I did this was very simple,  on clicking `delete` button, I ill store the `id` in the `state`. You can also store `index` of the array (if using array ) in the state. On delete success, store value will get updated - like there is a key in store says 'delete_success: true', if the state key is true, then splice the array element.

Comment: yes, I use array, and deleting works fine, the problem is that i have to reload the page to see that the item was deleted

Comment: @ you need to store the initial array to state, then after delete - update state. this will re-render component. 100%

Comment: Make sure your method `updateObject` returns a new object and doesn't mutates the state object. Also instead of new method for this, you can either use `Object.assign({}, state, {error: null, changed: true })` or `{ ...state, error: null, changed: true }` to avoid mutation. If you mutate the state object instead of replacing it with new object, redux will not realise that the state has change hence the component will not re-render.